# Let $U=\langle(1,0,1)\rangle$. Determine the equations of the orthogonal subspace of $U$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrix-calculus, orthogonality, invariant-subspace

> Let $U = \langle(1,0,1)\rangle$. Determine the equations of the orthogonal subspace of $U$ and an orthonormal basis of it. Obtain an expression for the vector $v = (-8, 3, 5)$ of the form $v = x+ y$, $x$ is in $U$ and y is in the orthogonal of $U$.

Thanks very much. I have been trying to do it but I don't think is right.

Comment: Hint: if a vector $v$ is orthogonal to a given vector $u$, then $v^T u = 0$. Can you use this fact to generate a basis for the orthogonal complement?

Comment: Why the tag abstract algebra?

Comment: yeah, i already generated the basis, but i dont know how to generate the orthonormal one @K.Jiang

Comment: if i divide each vector of the basis of the orthogonal subspace by its norm, would I obtain an orthonormal basis?

Comment: and the second part I dont know how can i solve it. I cannot come up with any idea.

Comment: @Lucía If you've obtained a basis, you can generate an orthonormal basis using something like Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: okay, so firts I would need to transform that basis in an orthogonal one, which it is already orthogonal, and then just to divide each component by its norm, right?

Comment: Correct, that normalizes the basis vectors.

Comment: Great! And in order to obtain such expression of v. How could I do that? Because i have been trying to sum different kind of vectors but not one gives that expresion.